# Difference between initializing with new operator and initializing with literal in Dart

Tags: dart, object-initializers

In Dart, what is the difference between initializing a `List<int>` with new operator and initializing it with literal?

case 1:

```
List<int> args = new List<int>(2);
args[0] = 1;
args[1] = 2;
```

case 2:

```
List<int> args = <int>[1, 2];
```

when I post the args to a native service port, the service port will receive different messages. The List instance initialized with new operator was serialized to Dart_CObject::kIntArray, but the instance initialized with literal was serialized to a Dart_CObject object with type 12.

Comment: I just sent this to someone on the Dart team that I think would be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

There's one tiny difference -- in the first case, you are creating a fixed-size list, while in the second case, the list is growable. If you used 'new List()' in the first case, there would be no difference. I'm not 100 % sure as I can't test it right now, but this is how I understand it (I know for sure that the VM has separate classes for fixed-size lists and growable lists).

Comment: thank you for your comment. but I want to know why they are serialized to different Dart_CObjects.

Comment: What if you have new `List<int>()` ? That is, remove the constructor parameter. Are they different CObjects?

Comment: Hi, Seth Ladd, I think that the `args` created in case 1 and the `args` created in case 2 is the same object. But in my Dart native extension, I receive different Dart_CObject. The `args` created with new List<int>() will be serialized to the CObjects as the same as <int>[1,2]. I think I understand the fixed-size list is different from growable list, and <int>[1,2] will create a growable list. Thank you very much.